# Need help with Arduino Love-O-Meter

Tags: hardware, electronics

not sure if this is the right place to post, but basically I am trying to make a Love-O-Meter, similar to the Arduino project example.

However, my method of determining the score is different. Instead of basing it on temperature, I am basing it on capacitance instead (Let me know if you think there are better ways to determine the score. I have tried body resistance, but it is too insensitive and I have also tried making it random but it doesnt make sense and its not as fun)

Another difference is that I want to make it only measure when both people place 1 of their hands on the foil and their other hand holding onto each other. However, the issue I have is Im not sure how to start measuring when the condition I mention happens.

Link to code: https://pastebin.com/bWyiDtfB (Using reference from here: https://playground.arduino.cc/Main/CapacitiveSensor?from=Main.CapSense) (The code starts measuring the capacitance when it detects that both foils have their hands placed on it, i.e.  when it detects that the capacitance exceeds a certain threshold, 200 for my case. It will then measure 100 samples and the score will be from the median of the 100 samples)
Link to fritzing diagram: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cOb7h.jpg (Ignore the black wire from A5)

Comment: I don't think you are going to get an answer here about a better way to measure "Love"   So then your whole question boils down to wating to  measure a connection between the two pads, as the two people would be completing the circuit between the two pads.  Do a little research, build a small test program for this "Sensor" only and post that code if you have any other questions about the specific problem you are having.

Comment: Basically the biggest problem I have now is to find a way to perform the measurement only when they hold hands and their other hand touch the foils.

Comment: that is simply a continuity test. Is there an electrical path from pad1 to pad2.  It will be very high resistance, but there will be an electrical path between them

Comment: I thought of trying to do that. Like connecting a 5V to 1 of the foil and the  analog pin to the other, but it will interfere with the capacitance measurement. Should I maybe make 2 more foils (1 connected to 5V and the other to the analog pin) so each person have to touch 2 foils with 1 hand?

Comment: Should be able to do both.  Can switch pin modes after deciding it us ready to start taking the reading. But them being joined could already effect the capacitance test

Comment: So what you are saying is that I dont code it to keep measuring the capacitance, but only start the measurement under the condition that the analogpin receives a signal right? Unlike what I am doing now, whereby I keep measuring the capacitance and only properly start the measurement when the capacitance exceeds the threshold.

Comment: @ChadG hmm I was thinking of adding a relay, so that when the hands are placed, the 5V will change to 1 of the digital pins instead.

Comment: The digital pins can be either output(5v) or input to measure capacitance.   So need to change which pin it's using, just change the pins mode

Comment: @ChadG so instead of using 5V, I use the digital pin to output a 5V. If so, then there shouldnt be any problem with the capacitance test right? I cant test it now but I will do so tomorrow.